# How to get value from radio buttons meta box, and return different contents?

Tags: user-meta, conditional-tags, get-template-part

I have a multiple checkbox type question (using Ultimate member) storing values as user meta.

The question basically asks the user what he wants, and according to what he wants, I would like my homepage to show different contents. Multiple values are possible.

My code is :

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$single = true;
$key = 'your_needs';
$needs = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 

if ( !empty($needs) ) : 

foreach ($besoins as besoin) :

if ( $need = "Option A") {

    get_template_part('front/option-a'); 

}


if ( $need = "Option B") {

    get_template_part('front/option-b'); 

}

if ( $need = "Option C") {

    get_template_part('front/option-c'); 

}


if ($need = "Option D") { 

    get_template_part('front/option-d'); 

}

endforeach;

endif;
```

This is only working halfway. It does return the correct template part, one after another, but regardless of whether or not is is checked. However I would like for my code to load the template part ONLY if current option is checked.

Also, keep in mind that I want the user to be able to check different options (ie. B and D -> loads template parts B and D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic case of `=` instead of `==`, ie. you're assigning values in a conditional statement, which always resolves to true:

```
if ( $need == "Option A") {

    get_template_part('front/option-a'); 

}
```